# Finding a value of a constant coefficient to get a specific zero in polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find the value of the constant a for which the polynomial $x^3 + ax^2 − 1$ will have $−1$ as $a$ zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should have hence $(-1)^{3}+a(-1)^{2}-1=0$ so $-1+a-1=0$ so $a=2$.